# How to loop through and read all documents in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

My `xyz_services` collection has three documents:

```
xyz_services

{
    service: "XYZ for under 1,500 sqft properties",
    minSize: 0,
    maxSize: 1500,
    price: 100,
    _id: "9LnnnJx3itBts8Bgp"
}
{
    service: "XYZ for 1,501 - 2,000 sqft properties",
    minSize: 1501,
    maxSize: 2000,
    price: 125,
    _id: "kmMnxuBfB2Qimdwkc"
}
{
    service: "XYZ for 2,001 - 3,000 sqft properties",
    minSize: 2001,
    maxSize: 3000,
    price: 150,
    _id: "jE8cPwRwkPmvRqZdB"
}
```

I get an integer `size` from a form submission.

Say that `var size = 2500`

I need to loop through each of the three individual documents in this `xyz_services` collection and see which document matches

`minSize <= size <= maxSize`

After I find the match I need to grab the `price` value from the document.

( In this case, for size = 2500, price would be 150 )

I'm totally uncertain how to write this - there's another SO question about looping through documents but I'm afraid it's over my head.

Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: You don't need to loop. Google mongodb's `$lte` and `$gte` query operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular you don't require to loop over all the documents in the collection. 
You can write down a simple query to that wil return only price of all the document that fulfill this condition `minSize <= size <= maxSize`

The query would be

```
      db.xyz_services.find({"minSize" : {$lte : 2500}, "maxSize" : {$gte : 2500}}, {_id : 0, price : 1})
```

This above query will return only price of all the document that fulfill the conditions. If you are using some driver like java or some other than you can pass the value of size (2500 in this case) dynamically also.

Comment: BTW, what does `{_id : 0, price : 1}` mean at the end of the query? I'm guessing that it returns only the `price` field but not the `_id` field?

Comment: This is projection part of the query, like what we write after select in the SQL query. And by default mongodb return the whole document that matches the query, but in your case as you require only price to be return so that we have asked mongodb to return only price. Mongodb returns it's primary key that is "_id" with every projection, so that we have explicitly asked mongodb to not to return it.

Comment: Doh, beat me to it. Gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use following snippet

> db.collection.findOne({"minSize" : {$lte : 2500}, "maxSize" : {$gte : 2500}}, {_id : 0, price : 1})

Answer (score 0):

FYI this is the full code that I used to return the value of "150"

```
db.xyz_services.findOne({"minSize" : {$lte : 2500}, "maxSize" : {$gte : 2500}}, {_id : 0, price : 1}).price
```